# What is meant by a "permanent working paper"?

Tags: publications, paper-submission

I just came across an Oxford University Associate Professor's personal webpage. After the sections of "publications" and "working papers", he also happened to have a section (with only one paper in it), titled "Permanent Working paper". While I do have a guess, I was hoping if someone could shed some light on the meaning of this. I imagine it is a paper that the author thought does not publish well, or that it has some interesting ideas, but it is not worth publishing. However, I may be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing what the paper is, it's hard to tell, but here is a situation where that might make sense:

Many permanent organizations -- say, the National Labs in the United States, NASA, or large research organization in other countries -- have an archive for papers that might not be research-y enough to be published in journals, but are still useful to be kept in a permanent archive. Think articles that provide very specific data about the aerodynamics of a particular wing shape that someone has investigated in the 1960s. Or an evaluation of certain materials to build a nuclear reactor. These are in essence the outcomes of engineering work, not of research, and are often not published in research journals.

These archives go by different names. "Permanent working paper" is one of the names that one could use for this. The point is that they are "working papers" in the sense that someone is "working with the data shown therein", and they are "permanent" in the sense that this is not work in progress.

Comment: I've seen plenty of university departments have these not sure why you call out national labs specifically?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Giving an example does not imply that there are no other examples one could *also* present :-)

Answer (score 2):

Might this be a text that is meant to be regularly updated, and never reach a final version? In this case the author may not want to publish it in a journal, although some journals do publish [living reviews](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Living_review).